# Should I use dynamic stackview inside UITableViewCell or use UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image]

Hello. I am building flights booking app, which has complex UITableViewCell. Basically, it is simple card with shadow, that has bunch of stackviews. First stackview, you see it on image is for labels. It is horizontal and dynamic. The next stackview shows flights. It has complex custom view, but for the sake of simplicity, it is shown with green border. It is also dynamic, so I need separate stackview for it. The next stackview is for airline companies that can handle this booking. I call them as operators. It is also dynamic, so I build yet another stackview for them. And of all these stack views are inside some core stackview. You can ask, why I created separate stack views instead of one? Because, labels above can be hidden. And also spacing in all stackviews are different.

1. It is really complex design. I followed above approach and build UITableViewCell. But performance is really bad. The reason is simple: I do too many stuff in cellForRowAt. The `configure` method of UITableViewCell is called everytime when the cell is dequeued. It means I should clean my stackview every time and after only that, append my views. I think it is really affects performance. I don't tell about other if/else statements inside cell. The first question is how can I increase scrolling performance of UITableViewCell in this case?
2. Some developers reckons that UITableView should be killed. UICollectionView rules the world. OK, but can I use UICollectionView with this design? Yes, of course, but above card would be one UICollectionViewCell and I simply don't avoid problem. The another solution is to build separate UICollectionViewCell for label (see on image), flight and operator. This would definitely increase performance. But, how can I make all of them live inside card?

P.S. What is inside my cellForRowAt method? There is only one `configure` method and assigning values to closure. But configure method is pretty complex. It gets some protocol which has bunch of computed properties. I pass implementation of that protocol to `configure` method. Protocol is like this:

```
protocol Booking {
  var flights: [Flight] { get }
  var operators: [Operator] { get }
  var labels: [Label] { get }
  var isExpanded: Bool { get set }
}
```

Implementation of this protocol is also complex. There are bunch of map functions and if/else statements. Some string manipulations. So, does that cause a problem? How can I solve it? By avoiding properties to be computed and just pass properties(flights, operators) to the implementation?

Comment: Without showing how "complex" your cells are, it's difficult to help. One possibility: instead of removing / re-adding subviews every time, only remove extra or add new subviews. Also, if you will have, say, a maximum of 10 "Operators" you could create 10 Operator labels (or views, whatever they are) when the cell is instantiated, and then show or hide as needed. And, depending on what you consider *really bad* performance, you may need to re-think your approach to your design.

Comment: I have configure method in my cell where I pass array of flights, array of operators, for instance. Then I add them to stackview. So, how can I know which of them are already added? Check for arrangedSubviews length? But UITableView calls cellForRowAt to reuse cells, so I suppose that some views will empty there, if I check length.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, without seeing complete detail, it's tough to help. And, it's a pretty broad question to begin with.

However, this may give you some assistance...

Consider two cell classes. In each, the "basic" elements are added when the cell is created -- these elements will exists regardless of actually cell data:

- your "main" stack view
- your "labels" stack view
- your "flights" stack view
- your "operators" stack view

To simplify things, let's just think about the "operators" stack view, and we'll say each "row" is a single label.

What you may be doing now when you set the data in the cell is something like this...

In the cell's init func:

```
    // create your main and 3 sub-stackViews
```

Then, when you set the data from `cellForRowAt`:

```
    // remove all labels from operator stack
    operatorStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // add new label for each operator
    thisBooking.operators.forEach { op in
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        v.text = op.name
        operatorStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
    }
```

So, each time you dequeue a cell in `cellForRowAt` and set its data, you are removing all of the "operator" views from the stack view, and then re-creating and re-adding them.

Instead, if you know it will have a maximum of, let's say 10, "operator" subviews, you can add them when the cell is created and then show/hide as needed.

In the cell's init func:

```
    // create your main and 3 sub-stackViews

    // add 10 labels to operator stack
    //  when cell is created
    for _ in 1...10 {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        operatorStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
    }
```

Then, when you set the data from `cellForRowAt`:

```
    // set all labels in operator stack to hidden
    operatorStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
        $0.isHidden = true
    }
    
    // fill and unhide labels as needed
    for (op, v) in zip(thisBooking.operators, operatorStack.arrangedSubviews) {
        guard let label = v as? UILabel else { fatalError("Setup was wrong!") }
        label.text = op.name
        label.isHidden = false
    }
```

That way, we only create and add "operator views" once - when the cell is created. When it is dequeued / reused, we're simply hiding the unused views.

Again, since you say you have a *"really complex design"*, there is a lot more to consider... and as I mentioned you may need to rethink your whole approach.

However, the basic idea is to only create and add subviews once, then show/hide them as needed when the cell is reused.

Comment: The situation is that I don't know how many operators I can get from the server. The requirements of the project is that it should be dynamic. The concrete amount is unknown. Then, how you would approach this?

Comment: @neo - again, without knowing your entire project, tough to say. There is more to app design than "I need to show all this data." Maybe you're trying to show too much all at the same time -- you also need to think about what the user will want to see. As an example (not directly related to what you're doing): suppose I want to show 5,000 records from a database? Would anyone want to scroll a 5,000 row table? Probably not. So... if your "cell" might have 100 "operators" do you think a user wants to scroll through all of them just to get to the next row?